# How to set session time out in PHP

Tags: php, session

How can i set the session time out in PHP if the user stays inactive for a certain time in a web page or when the user close the browser tab.

Comment: can you add some code example or some more detail Sajid.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237